# How do I set the image width and height of the html5 camvas in accordance to the size of a picture?

Tags: html, canvas

I have the following code.

It takes some base64 encoded picture from a database and display it on screen in a html5 canvas.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM editor_picture";

$rs = $db->GetAssoc($sql); //Getting the result in an array
$rs_array = array_values($rs);
$count_files = count($rs_array);
?>

`<script type="text/javascript">

 <?php for ($x = 0; $x < $count_files; $x++) { ?>

    var canvas<?php echo $x; ?> = document.getElementById('canvas<?php echo $x; ?>');
    var context<?php echo $x; ?> = canvas<?php echo $x; ?>.getContext('2d');

    var img<?php echo $x; ?> = new Image();    
    img<?php echo $x; ?>.onload = function  () {
       context<?php echo $x; ?>.drawImage(this, 0, 0, img<?php echo $x; ?>.width, img<?php echo $x; ?>.height);
   }
//$rs_array[$x]['editor_picture_use_base64'] contains the base64 encoded string
img<?php echo $x; ?>.src = "<?php echo str_replace(' ', '+', $rs_array[$x]['editor_picture_use_base64']); ?>";

<?php } ?>
            </script>


<?php
for ($x = 0; $x < $count_files; $x++) { 
?>
   <canvas id="canvas<?php echo $x; ?>" width="" height=""></canvas>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

Just like this http://jsfiddle.net/8fVvE/

It works but as the pictures are of different sizes I can not set the width="" height="" of the canvas manually

My question is:

How do I set the image width and height of the html5 camvas so it fits the size of the picture?

I would prefer to do it with native Javascript. But any solution will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the size of the canvas when the image has loaded, but before drawing.

You will want to use natural* size as this reflects the actual bitmap size of the image:

```
img<?php echo $x; ?>.onload = function  () {
   var canvas = context<?php echo $x; ?>.canvas;
   canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
   canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
   context<?php echo $x; ?>.drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.naturalWidth, this.naturalHeight);
}
```

The last to arguments are really not necessary, you could instead do:

```
   context<?php echo $x; ?>.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
```

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/8fVvE/36/)**